# Laravel 8 auth profile picture default

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm retrieving a users profile picture with:

```
Auth::user()->photo->thumbnail
```

In the user model I can see this:

```
public function getPhotoAttribute()
    {
        $file = $this->getMedia('photo')->last();
        if ($file) {
            $file->url       = $file->getUrl();
            $file->thumbnail = $file->getUrl('thumb');
            $file->preview   = $file->getUrl('preview');
        }

        return $file;
    }
```

However, when the user didn't upload a picture, I want to use a default picture. I have honestly no idea how. I've tried changing the function to this:

```
$file = $this->getMedia('photo')->last();
        if (!$file) {
            $file = asset("public/default.jpg");
        }

        $file->url       = $file->getUrl();
        $file->thumbnail = $file->getUrl('thumb');
        $file->preview   = $file->getUrl('preview');

        return $file;
```

But that gives "Call to a member function getUrl() on string".

Anyone could help me on the way!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Laravel asset() function returns the URL as string. Can see here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset

You can do something like this...
Just return your default image paths with the help of asset() function if the file doesn't exists.

```
public function getPhotoAttribute()
{
    $file = $this->getMedia('photo')->last();
    if ($file) {
        $file->url       = $file->getUrl();
        $file->thumbnail = $file->getUrl('thumb');
        $file->preview   = $file->getUrl('preview');
    } else {
        $file->url = asset("public/default.jpg");
        $file->thumbnail = asset("public/default-thumb.jpg");
        $file->preview = asset("public/default-preview.jpg");
    }

    return $file;
}
```